# When we have to use jest snapshots or manual checks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme, snapshot

I have code where I change the state of my react components and I want to write unit tests for them.

The code that I've written is full of these statements:

```
    expect(component.state().someArray).toBeDefined();
    expect(component.state().someArray).toEqual(EXPECTEDARRAY);

    expect(component.state().someArray.someNestedArray).toBeDefined();        expect(component.state().someArray.someNestedArray).toEqual(EXPECTEDINNERARRAY);
```

However, one collegue of mine suggested me to change it to:

```
    expect(component.state()).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Wow, using snapshot testing looks much much simpler. However, I see a bunch of articles where my approach is used.

So my question is: when we should use jest's snapshots and "matchers" for testing react components?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There is no golden rule to follow**

Snapshots simplify a testing by making test code shorter. They are also great for comparing test result against complex objects. Down side is that the snapshot is in a other file. When you are reading the test (which was maybe written by someone else), you have to open other file and figure out what results are actually expected here. Another bad thing is that they are easily updated to something that they are not meant to be update.

Old fashion assertions are not really good for comparing bigger junks of data. But the good thing is that you are not modifying the test unintededly. You have to go through the assertions and figure out you are doing the right thing.

By that being said, **I have followed the following protocol**:

- If the asserted object is big, use snapshots
- If the assert is against array, boolean, 
  string, number or small object, use old fashion asserts

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful :)